# Selecting similar Column names having common text in SQL Query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, sql-like

I am importing a CSV from a network drive, which has lots of columns containing text `SG_`. I am currently renaming these columns via code by running a 1st query to create a recordset with `SELECT TOP 1* FROM FILENAME.EXT` rows. Then i am looping the `recordset.Fields` and removing the prefixed text e.g. `nnn_` using `MID Function` and using the remaining text to use them as `Aliases` for these `SG` columns. So my 1st VBA created SQL string looks like this:

```
StrSQL = "SELECT [Food],[Bev],[Meds],[Average 1],[Midpoint],[Average 2],[SG_ABC],[SG_DEF],[SG_GHI]
```

From this, i want to pick up the columns containing `SG_`.

**Sample VBA Code:**

```
Set oCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set oRs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
strCon = "Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" & sFullDirectory & ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=Yes;"        

strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM " & FILE1
oCon.Open strCon
Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSQL)

i = 1
strSQL = "SELECT "

For Each Fld In oRs.Fields
    Select Case True
     Case Is = InStr(1, Fld.Name,"SG_") > 0
       TempSG=Trim(Mid(Fld.Name,InStr(1,Fld.Name,"SG_"),Len(Fld.Name)))
       strSQL = strSQL & " CDbl([" & Fld.Name & "]) AS [" & TempSG & "], "
....more Cases...

  End Select
Next Fld

oRs.Close
....more code.
```

Then i am joining this `strSQL` query to other tables for selecting other columns and loading the result to an ado recordset. I am currently using **Microsoft Access Text Driver** in Excel using VBA.

```
strSQL1 = "SELECT  G.[lbl], A.[tval], Q.*"
strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " FROM "
strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " (SELECT G.[pos], A.[pos], G.[lbl], A.[tval] FROM " & FILE2 & "  G," & FILE3 & " A WHERE G.[ID] = A.[ID])  T, (" & strSQL & ")  Q "
strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " WHERE (CLng(T.[G].[pos]) = CLng(Q.[gval])) AND (CLng(T.[A].[pos]) = CLng(Q.[pos]))"
strSQL1 = strSQL1 & " ORDER BY CLng(Q.[gval]), CDbl(Q.[Aggregate 1]) DESC, G.[lbl];"

Set oRs = oCon.Execute(strSQL1)
```

In the above code, `Q.*` represents the below table from which i want to only select the `SG_` columns. Hope this makes things clear. e.g.

```
SELECT  G.[lbl], A.[tval], Q.* LIKE 'SG_'
```

**CSV Table:**

```
Food   |  Bev |  Meds | Average |  Midpoint  |  Average  | 434_SG_ABC | 236_SG_DEF | 121_SG_GHI  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cheese | Rum  |  cold | 1.22    |  4.98      |   0.24    |  23.43     |  54.67     |  89.33      |
Butter | Wine |  heat | 3.56    |  2.40      |   0.98    |  12.12     |  90.23     |  33.43      |
Olive  | Beer |  rain | 4.33    |  7.11      |   1.45    |  11.55     |  10.31     |  87.22      |
Rice   | Gin  |  hail | 2.02    |  7.86      |   3.36    |  25.82     |  29.44     |  65.70      |
```

Is there a way to select these Columns?

Comment: How many columns do you have to need to build a dynamic query? Hundreds?

Comment: @Parfait it depends upon the client forecast. Most csv's may have 30-40 SGroups shown in columns. But some may have just 5. So it variates everytime.

Comment: You need to clean up the CSVs to the format you need and then handle with SQL which relies on structured data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way to achieve something like that.
You will either have to modify the VBA code to generate the string with the required columns.
Or if changing the VBA is not possible, insert the data in a staging table and then generate a Dynamic query for selecting the required data

```sql
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SELECT @query = @query + ',' + name
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_name(object_id) = '<Your Staging table name>'
AND name like 'sg%'

SET @query = 'SELECT ' + RIGHT(@query, LEN(@query)-1) + '
INTO <whichever permanent or temp table you need>
FROM <Your Staging table name>'

EXEC(@query)
```

This will give you the Select statement required for your details.

Comment: I am using Excel with VBA to create the SQL query.